# CSS running perfectly on local drive but not in XAMPP

Tags: html, css

First of, My version of Internet Explorer

- Internet Explorer 9.0.8112.16421
- and it has an Update Version of 9.0.28 (KB2957689)

and my XAMPP's version

- XAMPP 2.5
- Windows 6.1 Build 7600 Platform 2

My website stylesheet has CSS3 coding in it including the following:

```
box-shadow
border-radius
```

Now, when i run my website on my local drive without XAMPP, for example:

- C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Sample\index.html

The styles works perfectly fine, but when i run it on XAMPP (local server)

```
box-shadow
border-radius
```

does not work. why is that? thanks in advance!

ADDITIONAL

The directory of CSS and HTML in the XAMPP is

- htdocs\Sample\index.html
- htdocs\Sample\sample.css

Comment: you should put you project on `path_to/xampp/htdocs/` and run it as `http://localhost/Sample/index.html`. Have you?

Comment: looks like you have a separate CSS file, make sure that it's included correctly.

Comment: i have done that, the only ones that are not working are the CSS3

Comment: i have also included that using <link rel="stylesheet" href="wherever my css goes">

Comment: ***included*** does not mean you included it ***correctly***, your CSS file should be placed under the root folder of the local server, you can use relative path in your HTML code, if possible, you should tell about the path you included as well as where you placed the CSS file.

Comment: i edited the question, anyway the html file and the css are in the same folder so i used a relative path <link rel="stylesheet" href="sample.css">

Comment: so you can try adding more style to that CSS file to see if they take effect, also try refreshing your browser, even renaming the `index.html` and try it instead.

Comment: i also used other style like position, background-color, width, and height, it works fine, so it means the styles are being read but except for CSS3 styles

Comment: Did you also open the files under `htdocs\Sample` locally (not through XAMPP server)? It may be that the versions in htdocs and your desktop are different.

Comment: so have you tried using ***Element Inspector*** of the browser to see if the styles `box-shadow` and `border-radius` are there (loaded)?

Comment: yes i have tried opening it outside XAMPP, and CSS3 works just fine in my version of Internet Explorer

Comment: @KingKing no, box-shadow and border-radius are not loaded in Element Inspector when i run it on XAMPP, but when i run it locally i see them

Comment: @joshboley adding `/` to the front of the path indicates that the CSS file is at the root of the web site folder structure. It does **NOT** indicate a relative path. The OP's current `src` attribue (`sample.css`) is correctly defined if the OP wants to use a relative path.

Comment: @ Mike K.  Thanks, you're right.  I removed my incorrect comment